# Python find different Windows versions

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, wmi

I am looking to find Windows version using Python script.  I need to output version to a variable so I can perform commands based on Windows version.  So far i have this code in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wmi
import wx

conn = wmi.WMI()
app = wx.App()

for caption in conn.Win32_OperatingSystem():
    print("\nOS:", caption.Caption)

if caption.Caption == 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise':
    print("Wrong Windows version")
    
if caption.Caption == 'Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise':
    print("This is the correct Windows version")
    
wx.MessageBox(f'OS Version: {caption.Caption}', 'Operating System', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

I package this code using autopy and it runs correctly on Win10 with the output assigned.  When I run the same package on Win7 it doesn't return anything in the 'if' statement for Windows 7.  I use Python 3.8 and wxPython 4.0.7 both give me no trouble in running as exe on Win10 or Win7.  I just need it to output on Windows 7 "Wrong Windows version" so i know if statement is working on Win7.

Comment: can you print out `caption.Caption` on windows 7 and match that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for Wmi32 output string to assign a variable correctly on Win7 devices you would need to change

```
if caption.Caption == 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise':
    print("Wrong Windows version")
```

to

```
if caption.Caption == 'Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise ':
    print("Wrong Windows version")
```

You will need to add an extra space after Enterprise.  This fixed my issue.  Now script will run if statement in both Win10 and Win7.
https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2012/02/wmi-class-win32_operatingsystem-caption-property-may-contain-a-trailing-space.html